# Why dependencies of dynamic library has a specific directory in its file name

Tags: gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I found a strange thing when compiling my codes through gcc:
Dependent libraries have sometimes a directory preceding the filename (*.so), whiles usually it is just a *.so alike, without any directory before the filename, as is shown below:

```
 $>ldd Lib/libpagemanager.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffff65ef000)
    liblec.so.1 => /farequote/FQProduction/Dataware/CachingServices/Lib/liblec.so.1 (0x00007f7a897ed000)
    Input_API/MFaSTDeps/Lib/./liblmdb.so => not found
    liblz4.so.1 => not found
    libemmalloc.so.1 => /farequote/FQProduction/MiddleWareLibs/libemmalloc.so.1 (0x00007f7a895de000)
    libfqparams.so.1 => /farequote/FQProduction/MiddleWareLibs/libfqparams.so.1 (0x00007f7a89391000)
    libmfastlog.so.1 => not found
    libmfaststat.so.1 => not found
    libstdc++.so.6 => /farequote/FQProduction/GCCRuntime/Lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f7a89189000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007f7a88f10000)
```

In this example this library file looks for liblmdb.so which must comes from Input_API/MFaSTDeps/Lib. Other dependent libraries has not this constraint.

How does this come? What should I do to make this library depends on liblmdb.so that comes from any directory in LD_LIBRARY_PATH?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is wrong hardcoded rpath.

If you have no sources of problem lib to recompile without rpath option, use [chrpath utility](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chrpath)